# FileHelpers file access

Tags: asp.net, exception, filehelpers

I am trying to get my head over FileHelpers library and have main critical problem. When I try to implement it in my web app, or even use online demo I end up with "FileNotFoundException". The chosen file is being looked for on my C: drive. How can I make the FileHelpers code to access relative path to my application instead of absolute one?

[image: (screenshot from online demo)]

Regards,

Bartosz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Server.MapPath()` method to map a relative path (based on current directory or web-site root) to an absolute accessible path.

For example, if `yourfile.txt` is placed inside `App_Data` folder of your web-site then you can write:

```
Customer[] customers =
    (Customer[])engine.ReadFile(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/yourfile.txt"));
```

The tilde character represents the root of your web-site, if you specify a relative path then it'll be resolved as relative to the directory where your ASP.NET page resides.

Comment: A new error appeared: The type or namespace name 'MapPath' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Server' (are you missing an assembly reference?

Comment: Worked with my web app though. Thanks